# How to cite Stack Overflow surveys

Tags: discussion, support, survey

How should I cite the [Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2020](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020)?

*If possible in BibTeX format.*

---

This question was [originally asked in meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315057/how-to-cite-stack-overflow-surveys), but it was closed for being considered off-topic.

Emphasis is mine:

> DO NOT USE this tag unless your question's about the Developer Survey's integration with sites other than Stack Overflow. **Most questions about the annual Stack Overflow Developer Survey should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow**, not here.
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey

This question was also asked in [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/167062/how-to-cite-stack-overflow-surveys).

Comment: Is there clear data about the survey as a publication, i.e. author, title ("Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2020"), publisher, date/year, URL/doi, etc etc? If yes then perhaps one can build their own citation mimicking another publication? I fail to see drawbacks to such approach... If no, well, then this question definitely has merit.

Comment: Since your question is about referencing you could also have asked in https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question has since been asked at https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/167062/how-to-cite-stack-overflow-surveys

Answer (score 4):

I own a copy of "Cite Them Right: The Essential Referencing Guide" (11th edition). On page 57 they explain how to cite web pages with organisations as authors using the Harvard referencing style.

Your in-text citation would be:

> VBA was the most dreaded language in 2020 (Stack Overflow, 2020)

```
(<org name>, <year>)
```

And in your bibliography (or reference list):

Stack Overflow (2020) *Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2020.* Available at: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-languages-dreaded (Accessed: 2 May 2021)

```
<org name> (<year>) <page title>. Available at: <url> (Accessed: <date>)
```

*Note: since you can't include page numbers or other information to directly access the specific information you are referencing you could use a specific url like I did here. In doubt always check with your supervisor or librarian.*

Most reference managers have citations and exports features. I have used such a tool and it generated the same in-text citation and bibliography as above with the same referencing style.

Exporting the reference as BibTeX:

```
@misc{StackOverflow2020,
author = {{Stack Overflow}},
title = {{Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2020}},
url = {https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-languages-dreaded},
urldate = {2021-05-02},
year = {2020}
}
```

PS: I'm not entirely sure as to whether the organisation should be referred to as "Stack Overflow" or "Stack Exchange, inc."

Comment: It should be Stack Exchange, not Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is just a site on the network. It would be the equivalent of calling them Super User.

Comment: In the ToS you'll see that "Stack Exchange, inc" is also known as "Stack Overflow", "we" or "us". Hence why I'm not sure as to which denomination to use in citations and bibliographies. I understand that Stack Overflow is just one network in the exchange but that is not the point here.